# Detect changes in Blender object for more efficient export script

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, blender

I have a Blender file called Assets.blend containing over 100 objects for a game I'm developing in Unity.
When ever I make modifications, I run a script that exports each root object as a separate fbx file.
However I have no way of detecting which ones have been updated, so every time I have to re-export every single object even though I've only created/modified 1.
The time it takes to run the script is about 10 seconds, but then Unity detects the changes and spends over 30 seconds processing mostly unchanged prefabs.

How can I improve my script so that it knows which objects have been altered since the last export?
There does not appear to be any date_modified variable for objects or meshes.

Comment: Use Maya. Problem solved! You can update scene from Maya. No script or anything. All objects will be updated with one click.

Comment: yup get Maya.  open source is suck

Comment: Blender is free and Maya is not. For some indie devs that is significant.

Answer (score 0):

Blender does not record a timestamp of object modifications. My first suggestion would be to keep each object in it's own blend file, or maybe smaller groups of items in each file.

Another approach would be to change your export script, instead of exporting every object just export the selected objects. After you have changed an item or two, select the ones you changed and then export just those items.

```
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(obj.name+'.fbx')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to compute a CRC-like signature on meaningful values (mesh geometry, materials, whatever it is you change often) and store that somewhere (in each object as a custom property, for instance).
Then you can easily skip objects whose signatures did not change since last export.